# NodeJS script - npm doesn't show current installed version on exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, exec, nvm

I have a simple script that runs inside `/some/project/folder`

the script goes like this:

```
exec("npm -v", (err, stdout, stderr) => {


        $log.info('version installed', stdout);


    });
```

Now, when i run this node script it outputs `3.10.9` but when i go inside the `/some/project/folder` (by the terminal) and i run `npm -v` manually, it outputs `3.3.6`

**

> How this could be?

**

I am using nvm all the way down, but i don't understand if it's a problem with that or not.

**any advice**?

thanks

Comment: What do you get when you change exec to `exec("which npm", (err...etc` ? 
What do you get when you run `which npm` from the command line?

Comment: @LarryTurtis etc..../.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/npm

Comment: if i run npm outdated -g npm --json the infos are correct :O

Comment: In both cases (from command line and node script) you're getting the same executable file?

Comment: @LarryTurtis i am sorry and appreciated a lot your effort, now it is all fixed i don't know why today it works, maybe some sort of cache somewhere :O really don't know, thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting time, today it works i did not change anything so i don't know why yesterday no and today yes.

Crazy, thanks for your help anyway!